# CloudKit Sort Descriptor stops any records being returned

Tags: swift, sorting, cloud

Reasonably new CloudKit. Can anyone please tell me why the below fails to return any records? If I comment out  the query.sortDescriptors I get my records. The deployment is set to iOS 15.0. It's probably staring me in the face but I just can't see it :(

```
class func GetContactRecords(){
        
        StaticVarHelpers.ClearContacts()
        
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Contacts", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
        query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "contact", ascending: true)]
        
        CloudHelpers.dataBase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { ( records, _) in
            guard let records = records else {return}
            print("Contacts Total Records = \(records.count)")
            for BD in records{
                StaticVarHelpers.ContactsNotes.append(BD.value(forKey: "contactNotes") as! String)
                StaticVarHelpers.ContactsContactNo.append(BD.value(forKey: "contactNumber") as! String)
                StaticVarHelpers.ContactsContact.append(BD.value(forKey: "contact") as! String)
            }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it... In the CloudKit Console >>> Schema >>> Indexes >>> Contacts, I forgot to add 'contact' as Sortable.